# SQL to update stock levels

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I get this error when running the code below:

[image: Error]

```
Dim sqlSCIQty As String
Dim sqlSCQty As String

sqlSCIQty = "UPDATE [products/stock] INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion Items] " & _
"ON [products/stock].[Product Code] = [Stock Conversion Items].[Result PC] " & _
"SET [Stock Level] = ([Stock Level] + [Quantity]) " & _
"WHERE [Stock Conversion Items].[CutID] = " & Me.txtPCutID.Value & ";"

sqlSCQty = "UPDATE [products/stock] INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion] " & _
"ON [products/stock].[Product Code] = [Stock Conversion].[Source PC] " & _
"INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion Items] " & _
"ON [Stock Conversion].[SCID] = [Stock Conversion Items].[SCID] " & _
"SET [Stock Level] = ([Stock Level] - [Stock Conversion].[Quantity]) " & _
"WHERE [Stock Conversion Items].[CutID] = " & Me.txtPCutID.Value & ";"

Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute sqlSCIQty, dbFailOnError
db.Execute sqlSCQty, dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
```

I know that the first statement works and runs fine, but the second one throws up that error, i'm not familiar with such complex update statements so can anyone with any SQL knowledge spot anything?

Thanks in advance,
Bob P

Comment: have you tried with brakets () arround the inner joins. Cause when you have 2 inner join you have to wrap them with ().

Comment: Where do the brackets go? Around (INNER JOIN...ource PC]) ?

Comment: I posted my answer, gimme a feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this

```
sqlSCQty = "UPDATE (([products/stock] INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion] " & _
"ON [products/stock].[Product Code] = [Stock Conversion].[Source PC]) " & _
"INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion Items] " & _
"ON [Stock Conversion].[SCID] = [Stock Conversion Items].[SCID]) " & _
"SET [Stock Level] = ([Stock Level] - [Stock Conversion].[Quantity]) " & _
"WHERE [Stock Conversion Items].[CutID] = " & Me.txtPCutID.Value & ";"
```

You need brackets when you have more than 1 join in `ms-access`

Comment: This worked, Than you so much marc :) i'll mark it as the answer when I can!